# QAction "data" member not found

Tags: c++

As `openNote` is a `QAction` I can set its object name via `setObjectName`. Then why can't I have access to the data? I have no clue.

```
QAction *openNote; 
QVariant noteID;    
openNote = m_mainContextMenu.addAction(menuEntryName);
openNote->setObjectName("noteEntry");     //QAction::setObjectName

int ID = m_noteList[0].data()->getID();
noteID.setValue(ID);
openNote->setData(noteID);                //QAction::setData

connect(openNote,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(s_showNote()));
```

my slot:

```
void Traymenu::s_showNote(){
    QObject* obj = sender(); //sender is "openNote" of type QAction
    qDebug() << "objectName" << obj->objectName();  //works, because obj = QAction
    obj->data();      //no member data found?! Why? Documentation says there is...
```

My auto completion shows every member, e.g. `setData`, `objectName`, but not `data`. How can I get access to it?

If I write

```
QAction bla;
bla.data(); //<== auto completion shows "data"
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: because of type system

Comment: could you please explain that?

Comment: Ok I see that my obj is a QObject, but wasnt it originally a QAction? How to get around this?

Comment: `sender` can be of another type also. You can use `qobject_cast`.

Comment: Oh read about this, but did not work at first (error was sth. about templates). Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found out:

```
void Traymenu::s_showNote(){
    QObject* obj = sender();
    QAction *noteEntry = qobject_cast<QAction *>( sender() );
    int noteID = noteEntry->data().toInt();
    qDebug() << "noteID" << noteID;
}
```